# Error with reading from file to array

Tags: java, arrays, file

I am trying to read from a file and add each line from the file to my array "Titles" but keep getting the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Any Ideas? I am getting the error because of the line reading:

```
      Titles[lineNum] = m_line;
```

**My code:**

```
String[] Titles={};
int lineNum;            
m_fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("random_nouns.txt"));
m_line = m_fileReader.readLine();           
while (m_line != null)              
{       
        Titles[lineNum] = m_line;               
        m_line = m_fileReader.readLine();               
        lineNum++;              
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

array indexes start with 0. if length of an array is N, then the last index would be N-1. currently your array has a length of zero and you are trying to access an element at index 0(which does exist).

```
String[] Titles={};//length zero
```

and in your while loop

```
 Titles[lineNum] = m_line;  //trying to access element at 0 index which doesnt exist.
```

I would suggest you  use **ArrayList** instead of Array in your case. as ArrayList is dynamic (you dont have to give size for it)

```
     List<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();

       while (m_line != null)              
      {       
        titles.add(m_line);               
       }
```

Comment: Yes i understand that conceptually, but what is it that is causing this error? The way i understand it i: 
1) read a line 
2)add line to array position 0 
3)read next line 
4)incremement array position 
4) add to array then repeat until line is null

correct?

Comment: how can I determine the length of the whole file up front to set array length?

Comment: Thank you that makes great sense! Works much more efficiently and all is well in the world once again! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Array is not growable like ArrayList. Before you add element in string array you need to specify size of `String[]`

```
String titles[] = new String[total_lines] ;
```

or you can simply add each lines in `ArrayList` then finally convert into an Array like

```
int totalLineNumbers;
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();            
m_fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("random_nouns.txt"));                  m_line = m_fileReader.readLine();           
while (m_line != null)              
{       
        list.add(m_fileReader.readLine());

}
String titles[] = (String[]) list.toArray();
totalLineNumbers = titles.length ;
```

Comment: Is there a way to tell total lines in file up front so I do not have to read all the way through it to count the lines and THEN read again to add to array

Comment: @user1798913 Added. If you need to find total lines in file instead of whole file, you can simply do Runtime commands. for windows `type fileNam | find /c /v "~~"` and for linux `wc -l filename`